# Installing Node.js on Windows 10 always results in an error

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10

Hey I changed my System from Linux to Windows and I would like to install Node.js via .exe. The problem I have is, that I get an Error Pop-up. How could I fix it?

[image]

What I tried:

- I checked already the permissions and I got also the confirm-box for the admin and everything seems to be normal.
- Install Windows 10 ISO via bootable stick and Rufus in MBR and GPT and also by creating an usb via MediaCreationTool.

Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: I saw a question yesterday on SO with the same error message... you should look at yesterday's post and try to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I got in this issue too. There is already an approved bug on the maintainers GitHub: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224. So assume that a fix will be available in the next days.

Short term solution: Install the version before the latest (e.g. 14.17.1): https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224#issuecomment-872702653. This worked for me